# Issue while installing vagrant plugins

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-plugin

I have an issue when trying to install any of the vagrant plugins.

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
vagrant plugin install vagrant-awsinfo
```

The error that I end up getting is this:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-aws' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

Authentication is required for http://gems.hashicorp.com/.
Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running:
bundle config http://gems.hashicorp.com/ username:password
```

I am behind a proxy server. Not sure if this issue has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue without proxy. Looks like hashicorp would like to close free access to http://gems.hashicorp.com/